# QT C++ what is a good way to read a huge data from files and store it in memory?

Tags: c++, dataframe, qt5, qvector

I have audio data and I am not sure what is the best way to store it as matrix.
I have 4 large files of recordings from acoustic sensors, each file has 4 channels data interleaved.
I am using Qt C++ to do some treatements of these data. I already made this approach using QVector of QVectors to store the data in.

```
QVector<QVector<int>> buffer(16) // 4 * 4 : numberOfChannels * numberOfFiles

for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){ 
    QFile file(fileList[i]);    // fileList is QList of QStrings contains 4 files path
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        int k = 0;
        while(!file.atEnd()){
            QByteArray sample = file.read(depth/8); // depth here is 24
            int integerSample = convertByteArrayToIntFunction(sample);
            buffer[4 * i + (K%4)].append(integerSample);    
            k++;

        }
    }
}
```

To have at the end this matrix of 16 columns like below(f:file, c:channel):

f1c0 | f1c1 | f1c2 | f1c3 | f2c0 | f2c1 | ... | f4c2 | f4c3

But this approach it takes ages for large files of few gigabytes. I am wondering if there is another efficient way to fulfill this task and gain a lot of time. As I found, I can divide reading from files to chunks but still not clear for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: At a guess, I would say it "takes ages" because you are issuing 3-byte reads instead of reading multiple megabytes at once, and because you are using QVectors without presizing them. That means the vector has to be copied with every array doubling.

Comment: Thanks @Botje for the comment. How I could use QVectors with presizing? I didn't get it. 
About reading 3-bytes,  that's the sample size, which I need to convert each sample later. is there an optimal way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious antipatterns in your code.

The first one is not pre-sizing your `QVector`s. This means that every so often a call to `append` will notice that the vector's storage is full, which triggers an allocation of memory for a larger vector and then copying the contents of the vector before the `append` can complete. You know in advance how many samples are in each file, so you can use `QVector::reserve` to allocate the right amount in advance and inhibit this behavior:

```
const int bps = depth / 8;
QFile file (fileList[i]);
auto numSamples = file.size() / bps / 4; // "depth" bits per sample and 4 channels
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
  buffer[4 * i + j].reserve(numSamples);
}
```

Secondly, you are calling `file.read()` for every sample. This means you are repeatedly paying the cost of retrieving data (although buffering will alleviate this a bit) and that of allocating a `QByteArray`.
Instead, read a huge chunk of the file at once and then loop over that:

```
while (!file.atEnd()) {
  QByteArray samples = file.read(1'000'000 * 4 * bps); // read up to a million samples at once
  for (int k = 0; k * bps < samples.size(); k++) {
    QByteArray sample = samples.mid(k * bps, bps);
    buffer[4 * i + (k % 4)].append(convertByteArrayToIntFunction(sample));
  }
}
```

You can play around with the `1'000'000` number to see if there is a more optimal number, and you can probably gain a few percent more performance by passing `convertByteArrayToIntFunction` a `const char *`, but more readable is probably better.

Comment: It looks more clear now, I will try this and see. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't help with time, still takes a lot of time to fill the buffer.

Comment: How much is "a lot of time"? How big are these files? How fast is your disk?

Comment: it takes more than 30 minutes for 4 files of 4 GB. I am working with desktop environment and my computer disk speed is 2GB/s. I am not sure about the time, if it's normal or I can make it more optimal!

Comment: Taking the conversion from 3-byte samples to a 4-byte `int` into account, that takes 21GB of memory. Do you *have* 21GB of memory available? If not your system will start swapping out to disk and it will slow down to a crawl.

Comment: well, I have enough memory in the disk. Is it normal to take all that time ?

Comment: "enough memory in the disk" makes no sense. How much _working memory_ (RAM) do you have?

Comment: ah yes sorry, I meant I have enough RAM memory, it is 64G and 54G is available

Comment: Unless you are running this in debug mode or doing something spectacularly slow in `convertByteArrayToIntFunction` this should just work fine. On my system (Macbook Pro M1) it takes a minute to process a 4GB file with this code. (I used `QByteArray::toInt` for `convertByteArrayToIntFunction`) That is 66MB/s. Not blisteringly fast but..

Comment: Amazingly, replacing `samples.mid(k * bps, bps)` with `samples.mid(k * bps, bps)` reduces my runtime to 20 seconds, or 200 MB/s.

Comment: yes, I think the waste of time is in `convertByteArrayToIntFunction` function. It decompress and converts data, that's why I think it's slow. its code: 
`QString samp = QString(sample.toHex() + "00");
bool ok;
signed int decimalSample = samp.toUInt(&ok, 16);` 
That's causes the slow I guess.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use `QByteArray::toInt` directly? Just multiply by 256 if needed.

Comment: no, just was not sure how to decompress the 24bits to 32bits, that's why I use strings here, and as I learned recently, the strings are causing the slow. 
am gonna give it a try, thanks :)